# Typescript typecast existing variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I'm using a module of the following type:

```
interface AwesomeLibrary {
    name: string;
    query: Object;
}
```

I want to typecast `query` into another interface:

```
interface Query {
    startDate: string;
    endDate: string;
    showAll: boolean;
}
```

Let's say there is a function callback that gives me the `AwesomeLibrary`. I want to then typecast the `query` into `Query`. Right now this is all I have:

```
functionCb(response: AwesomeLibrary) {
    // This works fine
    let query: Query = response.query as Query;
    // Now, query.startDate is available
    // Do stuff to query
    // At the end, I want to send response back to another function, so I do
    response.query = query;
    otherFunction(response);

    // This does not work, but basically what I want:
    response.query = response.query as Query;
    // Then do stuff to response.query directly
    // Here response.query.startDate is not available, instead I have to use response.query['startDate']

    // Even this does not work:
    let query: Query = response.query as Query;
    response.query = query;
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type cast it like so:

```
(response.query as Query).startDate = (new Date()).toUTCString();
```

Or you can have another variable:

```
let response2 = response as AwesomeLibrary & { query: Query };
response2.query.startDate = (new Date()).toUTCString();
```

You can also receive the parameter in this type:

```
function functionCb(response: AwesomeLibrary & { query: Query }) {
    response.query.startDate = (new Date()).toUTCString();
}
```

But then you'll need to cast when calling this function.